# How to get text from url

Tags: python, url, urllib2, urlparse

I have some urls

```
http://go.mail.ru/search?fr=vbm9&fr2=query&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B&us=10&usln=1
https://www.google.ru/search?q=NaoOmiKi&oq=NaoOmiKi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8
https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%20%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4&clid=2073067
```

When I run this url in browser I get, that it's search of:

```
прогулка актеры
NaoOmiKi
откуда везут одежду в секонд хенд
```

I want to write code to get this values. I try

```
get = urlparse(url)
print urllib.unquote(get[4])
```

But it doesn't work correctly for all url. What I should use?

Comment: What doesn't work correctly? What result do you get?

Comment: Can you give an example of an URL for which it doesn't work and what you get instead?

Comment: @Jieter, `fr=vbm9&fr2=query&q=прогулка+актеры&us=10&usln=1` to first, `q=NaoOmiKi&oq=NaoOmiKi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8` to second and `text=откуда везут одежду в секонд хенд&clid=2073067` to third. it's not well

Comment: @raphv, `https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%83&clid=2073067` it return empty value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) parses a URL into 6 components: scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment. You correctly use index 4 to get the path.

The path however, is a `&`-separated string of key=value pairs with the values urlencoded. You try to unquote the entire string, while you are only interested in the value of the `text` or `q` key.

You can use [urlparse.parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) to parse the querystring and look for `q` or `text` keys in the returned dict.

Comment: hmm, `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'parse_qs'`

Comment: you must import both urlparse and parse_qs from urlpars: `from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs`